Powerbi Matrix Not Subtotaling
Ok, so what I'm really after is the "Show grand totals for rows" feature that is in the Pivot Table options in Excel but I need it in PowerBI.
In my matrix table I have 3 items in my hierarchy: Division -> Category -> Manufacturer
I want to limit the manufacturers shown because only the top 5 matter really.
So I followed this here to try to get it to work: Solved: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Hide-rows-in-matrix-table-without-affecting-subtotal/td-p/2321507
At first, I tried it with a RANK option to truly return the top 5 items with this DAX:

VAR ManufacturerRank = RANKX(ALL('Product'[Manufacturer]), [Total Dollar Sales], , DESC)
RETURN
    IF(
        ManufacturerRank <= 5
        , [Total Dollar Sales]
        , BLANK()
    )

For the most part, this worked except that my data is additive up from an item level so the Rank was giving me some weird results showing a lot more than 5 Manufacturers by category and it was showing some with low dollar amounts and excluding others with high dollar amounts.
So I pivoted and created a dataflow excel file with a list of explicit Manufacturers that I want displayed per category.
I created a relationship between this new table and the exsiting product table based on the Category columns, then I created this new measure:
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Manufacturer]) IN VALUES('Category Competing Manufacturers'[Manufacturer])
    , [Total Dollar Sales]
    , BLANK()
)

Everything about this measure works exactly how I want it to except there's no subtotal.

I basically want the first column to subtotal like the second column is doing.
